# .htaccess brings 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$    index.php?pageLevel1=$1&pageLevel2=$2&pageLevel3=$3 [L,R=301]
```

And when I try to access the page it gives me '500 Internal Server Error'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably don't have mod_rewrite enabled. you need to check your log. But if it's not enabled it doesn't know what RewriteEngine on is and will get a 500 error

Comment: You are **right**. The module wasn't activated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me -- check if you have `mod_rewrite` enabled like @Panama Jack suggests.

```
a2query -m rewrite
```

If it doesn't say enabled, then enable it:

```
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

Also you probably want to remove the first slash in rule, if your base is `/`, so it becomes:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$    index.php?pageLevel1=$1&pageLevel2=$2&pageLevel3=$3 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to direct traffic to the URL index.php?pageLevel1=$1&pageLevel2=$2&pageLevel3=$3

The 500 Error is shown because it cannot understand the rule ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$

Please refer the following guide,

https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: The OP already fixed the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33493187/htaccess-brings-500-internal-server-error#comment54770673_33493187